# Simple but very long request

Tags: performance, neo4j, request, cypher

I'm trying to do this simple request :

```
MATCH (p:Player)
MERGE (a:Alias {name:p.name})
MERGE (p)-[r:AKA]->(a)
RETURN count(*)
```

It will register every old nickname for a player.

I just want to create/merge a node Alias for each Player, and connect them.

There are around 100k Player nodes.

I don't understand why it's taking so long.

When I'm describing the request, I have :

[image]

I really don't understand why I have a branch with around 3 billions rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First improvement you can do is to create an index on :Alias(name) , you will see already a crazy difference in the query :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Alias(name);
```

Comment: That was miraculous ! :) Thank you !